# Comparing 2 different uncertainty of KE of particle equations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I come across the uncertainty of KE of a particle in a box as:

$$\Delta KE = \frac 12m[2v\Delta v\ +\ (\Delta v)^2]$$
I try to apply this equation by assuming an electron was placed in a 1-D box has a width of 10nm (uncertainty of x) and I believe $\lambda \approx \Delta x$.

This is what I tried:

$\Delta p\Delta x \ge \frac12\hbar$

$\Delta v \ge \frac{h}{m4\pi\Delta x} = \frac{6.626*10^{-34}}{(9.109*10^{-31})(4\pi)(10*10^{-9})} = 5788.56\ m/s$

$v = \frac{h}{m\lambda} = \frac{6.626*10^{-34}}{(9.109*10^{-31})(10*10^{-9})} = 72741.24\ m/s$

$\Delta E = \frac12 (9.109*10^{-31})[2(72741.24)(5788.56)+(5788.56)^2] = 3.98811*10^{-22}\ J$

Is my application of that uncertainty equation possible because I usually come across another equation which is:
$\Delta KE = \frac{p^2}{2m}$

Is there any differences between these 2 uncertainty equations?

Comment: There are a few issues. (1) In going from your first inequality to your second, you replaced $\Delta p$ with $\Delta v$. This is incorrect since momentum and velocity don't have the same units. You should use $\Delta p = m \Delta v$ where $m$ is the mass of the electron. (2) The kinetic energy is $KE=\frac{p^2}{2m}$, so the uncertainty in kinetic energy wold be $KE=\frac{p \Delta p}{m}$, which should agree with your first formula. (3) There's no need to include the $(\Delta v)^2$ term in $\Delta KE$, it is very small compared to $v \Delta v$. (4) You shouldn't quote so many significant digits.

Comment: @Andrew can you briefly explain how $p^2 = p\Delta p$ ?

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin Maybe the infinitesimal form is simpler to understand $\mathrm{d}p^2 = 2p\,\mathrm{d}p$? This is just saying that $\mathrm{d}p^2/\mathrm{d}p= 2p$.

Comment: @DavideMorgante Okay, so uncertainty is the same thing as a derivative? That doesnt seem right.

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin Obviously not. But what are you trying to evaluate is a finite difference $\Delta p$ which mathematically behaves like a derivative which is not infinitesimally small.

Comment: @DavideMorgante Obviously. But then why is the uncertainty relation being used?

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin Arg I meant to write $\Delta KE = \frac{p \Delta p}{2m}$. Since $(p+\Delta p)^2 - p^2 = 2 p \Delta p + (\Delta p)^2 \approx 2 p \Delta p$ assuming $\Delta p \ll p$.